# Uninstall group of applications using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am getting group of application that i want to uninstall by using this command:

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {  $_.Name -match "Microsoft sql" }
```

$app is list of applications.
Can i uninstall the complete group or i must loop with foreach?

PowerShell version -3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an *object array* depicting a set of *individual* applications (ManagementObject).

Applications are uninstalled individually. Use a % loop!

```
$app | % { $_.Uninstall() }
```

Comment: Yes! If you type "Alias %" you will see that it is aliased to the ForEach-Object commandlet.